# Google admin sdk - user usage reports not available

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I would like to ask you for help with google admin sdk, User Usage Reports. I got following questions:

1. One of the parameters used to retrieve a usage reports is a date. Unfortunately for current date the reports are not yet available - I must use a date few days in the past. Is there any official rule, recommendation or any advice how to know most recent date for which the reports are already available?  Should I query reports for a one day in the past, 3 days, week or...? I just want to have the latest results without worrying about the date...

Even more: sometimes the returned reports are OK for one of the google apps but for other one - like docs - I got warning that its not ready. So my question is: how to get most recent data for all of the apps? (mainly: accounts, docs, gmail).

I am using "all" parameter to retrieve all accounts at once.

2. Second question is related to first one: assuming I receive partial data - for example no reports for docs - is it possible that when I retrieve reports for all accounts (emails) some of them will have reports ready and some of the only partial data? Or the reports are always either ready or partial and for all accounts (emails) I should expect the same, full or partial data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any official rule, recommendation or any advice how to know most recent date for which the reports are already available? Should I query reports for a one day in the past, 3 days, week or...? I just want to have the latest results without worrying about the date...

[UserUsageReport](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport) returns Google Apps service activities across your account's users. the get() method retrieves a report for a set of account users. You can query for any date value provided that its timestamp is represented as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and should use your account's timezone.

> how to get most recent data for all of the apps? (mainly: accounts, docs, gmail).

I'm guessing you're using [CustomerUsageReport](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/customerUsageReports/get), it may take a while to process a report and thus you may have to retry to call it again after a few hours.

> Second question is related to first one: assuming I receive partial data - for example no reports for docs - is it possible that when I retrieve reports for all accounts (emails) some of them will have reports ready and some of the only partial data? Or the reports are always either ready or partial and for all accounts (emails) I should expect the same, full or partial data?

I think this will depend on if the data are now available or not. You can test out various parameter values when accessing the API to test it out.