# API User Usage Report: Inconsistent Reporting

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

I'm using a JVM to perform API calls to the Google Apps Administrator API.

I've noticed with the User Usage Reports, I'm not getting complete data when it comes to a field I'm interested in (num_docs_externally_visible) and the fields which form that fields calculation. I generally request a single day's usage report at a time, across my entire user base (~40k users).

According to the documentation on the developer's, I should be able to see that in a report 2-6 days after; however after running a report for the first 3 weeks of February, I've only gotten it for 60% of the days. The pattern appears to be random (in that I have up to 4 day in a row streaks of the item appearing and 3 days in a row streaks of it not, but there is no consistency to this).

Has anyone else experienced this issue? And if so, were you able to resolve it? Or should I expect this behavior to continue if this is an issue with what the API is returning outside of my control?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only natural that the data you get is not yet complete, it takes a certain day to receive the complete data.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609038/google-admin-sdk-user-usage-reports-not-available?rq=1) is not exactly the same of your question, but i think it will help you. Especially the part that you need to use your account time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What that question is saying and what you're saying does make sense. However, since there's no mention of it in the GAPI admin guide, it's hard to know how to proceed.

Since I'm using a script to make the API call then write the output to a file after reformatting the JSON, it's difficult from my POV to know how I should design it to work well with Google's rules. 

According to their site, if we wait ~6 days we should get the complete set of attributes from the usage report; however it does not seem to be the case every time.